# Socket io in React Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, socket.io

I am using Socket.io for my *react-native* project. The nodejs server is hosted with Heroku. When I tried to connect from the app to server, it works perfectly !! But when try I emit a message, I can't see it on my receiving *Reactjs* site 
Here's the code for react native app ->

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

useEffect(() => {
if (tried === true) {
  const socket = io("wss://my-domain-name.herokuapp.com");

  socket.emit("finishPayment", "true");

  setScanned(false);
}
}, [status]);
```

Here's the *receiving* client side code (React js) ->

```
socket.on("finishPayment", (msg) => {
  console.log(msg);
});
```

The connection is done (in the app), but the message is not emitted. 
Any idea why is this happening ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it !!! Here's the final code ->

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Alert } from "react-native";

navigator.__defineGetter__("userAgent", function () {   // you have to import rect native first !!
 return "react-native";
}); 

import SocketIOClient from "socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js";
 
  //

  useEffect(() => {
const socket = SocketIOClient("wss://site-name.herokuapp.com/", {
  jsonp: false,
});
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("connected");
  socket.emit("hello", "world");
});

socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(err instanceof Error);
  console.log(err.message); 
});
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

On android (locally) the problem for me was that I did not open the connection between mi socket serve and react native app. Just run adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000 on the terminal and the server ports will be opened for connection. I use 3000 for my server but change it to your server's port locally.

```
adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I faced this issue because of multiple reasons. here is the list of the problems and the solutions.

**Problem 1:**
on the server side I updated the socket.io package without having a look at what is the new in docs to implement the new version and after I re-reading and follow the docs it turns out that ***I'm using the old import***

```js
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const io = socketio(server);
```

and I changed the import to the new way like below

```js
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
```

**Problem 2:**
On the React Native client side I also updated the socket.io to `V4.7.1` ***which is the same version as the server side version*** and after reading the latest docs it turns out also I'm using the wrong imports, so I changed from this

```js
import io from "socket.io-client";
```

to this

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
```

**Problem 3:**
I was using the `http://localhost:5000` as the socket URL, but it turns out this will not work at least on Android emulator, so I used my local ip instead `http://192.168.1.100:5000` and I need also to add `transports` property to make it fully work like the example below:

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("http://192.168.1.100:5000", { transports: ["websocket"] });
```

---

***Bonus***
*always use this events on the client side to make sure that you are connected or not and to see the errors*

```js
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("Socket Connected");
});

socket.on("connect_error", (error) => {
  console.log("Socket Error", error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is much cleaner.

```
 const io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io');

 const socket = io(
    `API URL`,
    {
      transports: ['websocket'], // you need to explicitly tell it to use websockets
    },
  );

  socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('connected --------------- socket ---------------');
  });

  socket.on('connect_error', err => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

Comment: But what do we put in API url? Do we prefix it with `ws://` do we use our IP address `localhost`? What?

Comment: that depend on your server. if its websocket protocol, then ws://